# howto write an LDAP schema?

Tags: ldap

i want to introduce a new class "MyAppValues".

when you add this to class to an existiting objects it should be possible add the following attributes:

- MyAppKey is a mandantory string, that cannot be emtpy
- MyAppOptionalValue is an optional string, that can be empty

How can this be done?

Is there an easy tutorial out there?

Comment: Changed your title and tags. The answer applies to all LDAP servers, not just OpenLDAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your own schema, read [this page](http://zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch3/) to understand the LDAP schema basics and
then you can use [Apache Directory studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) to create the schema.